# How do I solve a system of equations containing a modulus function?

Tags: systems-of-equations, collatz-conjecture

I'm trying to solve this system of equations for $a$:
$$\frac{3n+1}{2^{a-1}} \mod 2 = 1$$
$$n \mod 2 = 1$$
for any odd input $n$.

I know that there is only $1$ solution for every possible $n$ value. For example, if $n=9$, then $a=3$, however, I am unable to solve algebraically for $n$. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Re-phrase the question: $$\frac{3n+1}{2^{a-1}}\text{ is an odd integer}\\n\text{ is an odd integer}$$

Comment: It seems that you are after $v_2(3n+1)+1$  where, as usual, $v_p(m)$ denotes the greates power of $p$ that divides the integer $m$.  There is no universal way to compute that, though for numberts of sensible size it isn't difficult

Comment: To find $\ a\ $, you can simply start calculating the binary representation of $\ 3n+1\ $:
\begin{align}
&\hspace{0.8em}r_0=3n+1\\
&\hspace{0.8em}b_0=r_0\pmod{2}\\
\text{While $\ b_i=0\ $, do }&\cases{b_i=r_i\pmod{2}\\
r_{i+1}=\frac{r_i-b_i}{2}\\
i\rightarrow i+1\ .}
\end{align}
You can stop when you reach the first $\ i\ $ with $\ b_i\ne0\ $.  You'll then have $\ a=i+1\ $. That is, $\ a\ $ is one more than the number of trailing zeroes in the binary expansion of $\ 3n+1\ $.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4663150/1162072

Answer (score 0):

By definition if $x \mod 2 = 1$, then $x$ is odd.

If $n$ is guaranteed odd, then the second equation is guaranteed.

The numerator $3n + 1$ of the first equation is always positive and even. But after dividing by $2^{a-1}$ we want the output to be odd. Thus, this problem is in a way about prime factors. Think of the prime factorization:

$$3n + 1 = 2^{x} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{b} p^{\, x_i}_{\,i}$$.

$x$ represents the number of $2$'s in the prime factorization of $3n + 1$. By definition of the primes greater than $2$, $p_{\, i}$ must be odd for every $i$. With this, we know

$$ \frac{3n+1}{2^{a-1}} = 2^{x - a + 1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{b} p^{\, x_i}_{\,i}$$

and this number can only be odd if $a = x + 1$ (if $a < x + 1$, there would be a $2$ left which makes it even, and if $a > x + 1$, the modulus would be a fraction).

This all being said, I don't think there is an analytical closed-form formula for the number of $2$'s in the prime factorization of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed $\; a>1 \;$, different solutions can be found for $\; n$

if $\; a \;$ even then $\quad n \equiv \frac{5 \cdot 2^{a-1}-1}{3} \pmod {2^a}\;$  are solutions

if $\; a  \; $ odd then $\quad n \equiv \frac{2^{a-1}-1} {3} \pmod {2^a}\;$  are solutions

Or given $n$ odd you can analyze its binary representation starting from the least significant bit for example:

$   \cdots 11\quad ,\quad \cdots 1101\quad, \quad \cdots 110101 \quad, \quad \cdots11010101 \quad, \quad \dots \quad $

which corresponds to

$   a=2\quad ,\quad a=4 \quad, \quad  a=6\quad, \quad  a=8\quad, \quad \dots \quad $

or

$   \cdots 001\quad ,\quad \cdots 00101\quad, \quad \cdots 0010101 \quad, \quad \cdots001010101 \quad, \quad \dots \quad $

which corresponds to

$   a=3\quad ,\quad a=5\quad, \quad  a=7\quad, \quad  a=9\quad, \quad \dots \quad $